# Apps Script trigger API call on every new row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This app script listens to a POST request and returns the data into a sheet

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
  params = JSON.parse(params);
  var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var testRunUrl = myData.test_run_url;
  var testRunName = myData.test_name;
  var testRunEnv = myData.environment_name;
  var testRunResult = myData.result;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
  var timestamp = new Date();



  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(timestamp);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(testRunName);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(testRunEnv);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 4).setValue(testRunResult);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5).setValue(testRunUrl);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(params);  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
}
```

On column 6 params value is as follows (example)

```
{"resource":"https://api.mercadolibre.com/collections/notifications/2951993376","topic":"payment"}
```

I need to fire an api call based on the url in params value and return the email value and post it back to the corresponding row within the sheet.

so for the above example API call would be to url: 
https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/2951993376?access_token=APP_USR-7641393791309669-082521-8426042efc7686ae9bff4b135f5gdhfa-270831598

For each new row I need to fire an API call to:

```
https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/[ID]?access_token=APP_USR-7641393791309669-082521-8426042efc7686ae9bff4b135f5gdhfa-270831598
```

and return back "payer.email" value into column 7 of that row repeating that for every new row.

This function returns the payer.email value

```
function myFunction() {

var url="https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/5267820258?access_token=APP_USR-7641393791309669-082521-8426042efc76errae9bfg5513ff53dffa-270831598";
var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var json=response.getContentText();
var data=JSON.parse(json)
var emailmercadopago=data.payer.email; 
Logger.log(emailmercadopago);
}
```

Example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h1Ckrv_NM0evc_0ons_d6xZvy-DWy8rYIqG0vIHWMpg/edit?usp=sharing

But i cant put them together how I want. 
How can i fire such api call on each new row added and return the email back to the row within the sheet on column 7

**UPDATED**
This is how it looks like now but its not working:

```
function getEmailFromParams(params) {
  var resource = JSON.parse(params).resource;
  var id = resource.substring(resource.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  return getEmailFromid(id);
}

function getEmailFromid(id) {
  var url="https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/"+id+"?access_token=APP_USR-7641393791309669-082521-8426042efc7686ae9bff4b13ff53dffa-270831598";
  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json=response.getContentText();
  var data=JSON.parse(json)
  try {
    var emailmercadopago=data.payer.email || "No Email"; 
    return emailmercadopago;
  } catch (err) {
    return "Problem getting Email";
  }
}


function doPost(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
  params = JSON.parse(params);
  var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var testRunUrl = myData.test_run_url;
  var testRunName = myData.test_name;
  var testRunEnv = myData.environment_name;
  var testRunResult = myData.result;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
  var timestamp = new Date();

  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(timestamp);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(testRunName);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(testRunEnv);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 4).setValue(testRunResult);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5).setValue(testRunUrl);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(params);

  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 7).setValue(getEmailFromParams("F"+(lastRow+1)))

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");

}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @Cooper How can i fire such api call on each new row added and return the email back to the row within the sheet on column 7

Comment: Your can replace this `sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(timestamp);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(testRunName);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(testRunEnv);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 4).setValue(testRunResult);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5).setValue(testRunUrl);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(params);  
` with this `var vA=[[timestamp,testRunName,testRunEnv,testRunResult,testRunUrl,params]];
sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,6).setValues(vA);`

Comment: I dont need to send any email, i just need to get the emaail from the api call. Please re read

Comment: Okay.  Well the answer is still why not just initiate it from the doPost() script?

Comment: @Cooper yes that is the idea but i dont know how cuz i have to build the url from info previously gathered

Comment: And where do you keep that previously gathered information?

Comment: @Cooper everything is laid out in the post, even the test sheet.

Answer (score -1):

To get this you could create a custom formula function.

Create this:

```
function getEmailFromParams(params) {
  var resource = JSON.parse(params).resource;
  var id = resource.substring(resource.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  return getEmailFromid(id);
}

function getEmailFromid(id) {
  var url="https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/"+id+"?access_token=APP_USR-7641393791309669-082521-8426042efc7686ae9bff4b13ff53dffa-270831598";
  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json=response.getContentText();
  var data=JSON.parse(json)
  try {
    var emailmercadopago=data.payer.email || "No Email"; 
    return emailmercadopago;
  } catch (err) {
    return "Problem getting Email";
  }
}
```

then on your post function you can do:

```
function doPost(e) {
//...
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(params);  
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 7).setValue(getEmailFromParams(params));  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
//...
}
```

or

```
function doPost(e) {
//...
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(params);  
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 7).setFormula("=getEmailFromParams(F"+(lastRow+1)+")");  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
//...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: please check original post at the bottom i updated the code but its not working. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: please help? im not sure if code doesnt work or if i misplaced it

Comment: its notupdating anything at all on column 7

Comment: Hello @sebas, sorry for the mistake! In your case, please change SetFormula with SetValue. Read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to help you understand why i created those two methods.

Comment: @ZekctorH i did update the function on my original post and on the script itself but its still not working. Its only posting the values up to column 7 and not updating any info on column 7 even with setvalue

Comment: did you check it out?

Comment: it's still not updating anything on column 7

Comment: Hello @sebas. I had created a copy of your spreadsheet and tested the function in there. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pOYkEEybWKSj7nqnXMuscFEBTVgr8mYuhMjDlh45S9s/edit?usp=sharing) is a link for the copy of your sheet that I made.

Comment: i did send you a request to access it

Comment: Hello @sebas, request accepted. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: i see that its working but i cant see your full app script code.Can u please update your answer to showcase your full code?

Comment: Hello @sebas, the code I have in my sheet is the same as the one I provided to you, except I don't have the `function doPost(e) {` part.

Comment: I have pasted the exact code im using on my original post under "UPDATED" and its not working what am I missing?

Comment: You are using the formula instead of passing the value of your "resources". I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @sebas, it's already edited. `sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 7).setValue(getEmailFromParams(params)); ` is the key. Remember to accept the answers that are helpful to you!